# How to get second value of multi value ldap attribute

Tags: ubuntu, gmail, openldap

We have ldap attribute name "mail" , which have multiple values like

mail: user1@exmaple.com

mail: user1@demosite.com

Now I am looking for the query which will return result only second value
mail: user1@demostie.com

```
ldapsearch -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -xw $PASS -LLL -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -b 
"ou=workers,dc=example,dc=com" "(&(mail=*demosite.com))"
```

but above query is returing both the email ids. I want only second one. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: There is no `user1@demostie.com` in your ldapsearch ... text

Comment: thanks for the comment. I am trying to sync google email password using google cloud directory. but it is changing the priamry email password only for all the users. I wanted to list secondary email ids of all the users so I can sync that.

Comment: I have added another field in LDAP tree like second-email-id and configured that field in google cloud directory sync. By default LDAP do not provide any option to print only second value in multi value parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in an LDAP search, you will need some additional processing around it. For one thing, there's almost certainly no guarantee of the order of attributes and values returned by a search.

Answer (score 0):

Some LDAP servers, e.g. OpenLDAP, support the *valuesReturnFilter* control (see [RFC 3876](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3876)).

You can use this control with OpenLDAP's *ldapsearch* with CLI argument -E.

Example: `-E "mv=((memberOf=cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir))"`.

Note that the filter is a so-called simple filter **without** operand.

Example with my on-line demo of [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com):

Without the control:

```
$ ldapsearch -H "ldaps://demo.ae-dir.com" -b "ou=ae-dir" -s sub -x -D "uid=aead,cn=ae,ou=ae-dir" -w CorrectHorseBatteryStaple -LL "(memberOf=cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir)" memberOf
version: 1

dn: uid=dsrg,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
memberOf: cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
memberOf: cn=test-users-3,cn=test,ou=ae-dir

dn: uid=rqei,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
memberOf: cn=test-users-1,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
memberOf: cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
```

With matched values control:

```
$ ldapsearch -H "ldaps://demo.ae-dir.com" -b "ou=ae-dir" -s sub -x -D "uid=aead,cn=ae,ou=ae-dir" -w CorrectHorseBatteryStaple -LL -E "mv=((memberOf=cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir))" "(memberOf=cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir)" memberOf
version: 1

dn: uid=dsrg,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
memberOf: cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir

dn: uid=rqei,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
memberOf: cn=test-users-2,cn=test,ou=ae-dir
```